# Keen IO - Set min / max for Y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, keen-io

I've downloaded a dashboard sample using Keen and I'm tyring to set a MIN / MAX value for the Y axis.

I've tries this SO post which didn't work for me:
[Maximum and Minimum Y-Axis Values on Keen.io Dashboard Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839311/maximum-and-minimum-y-axis-values-on-keen-io-dashboard-charts)

Below is my code:

```
  var chart = new Keen.Dataviz()
    .el('#chart-01')
    .type('area')
    .height(280)
    .stacked(false)
    .title('Trades Per Symbol')
    .prepare();

    chart
    .data(data)
    .render();
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it..

For anyone else struggling:

```
chart
.data(data)
.chartOptions({
    axis: {
        y: {
            min:10,
            max:20
        }
    }
})
.render();
```

Comment: I was plying with this and I found to get the yaxis at zero I had to set min to -2. strange.